# Can Meshlab export the surface curvature of each point/vertex in a mesh?

Tags: mesh, meshlab

I'm new to MeshLab and surface curvature.
I'm trying to find/store the curvature of a specific vertex of a 3D mesh (obj).
I know that Meshlab's filters - normal, curvature, orientation - functions can help to find the curvature range of a mesh, I've been searching but haven't found a way to find the curvature of a specific vertex in Meshlab.
I would appreciate some advice on how to do that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compute Gaussian or Mean curvatures, the values are stored as quality values in vertex. You can export the mesh to  a format that support quality, for example Ply ascii